# Combine table and matrix with R

Tags: r

I am performing an analysis in R. I want to fill the first row of an matrix with the content of a table. The problem I have is that the content of the table is variable depending on the data so sometimes certain identifiers that appear in the matrix do not appear in the table.

```
> random.evaluate
     DNA LINE LTR/ERV1 LTR/ERVK LTR/ERVL LTR/ERVL-MaLR other SINE
[1,]  NA   NA       NA       NA       NA            NA    NA   NA

> y
  DNA          LINE      LTR/ERVK      LTR/ERVL LTR/ERVL-MaLR     SINE 
    1             1             1             1             1       4
```

Due to this, when I try to join the data of the matrix with the data of the table, I get the following error

```
random.evaluate[1,] <- y
Error in random.evaluate[1, ] <- y : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Could someone help me fix this bug? I have found solutions to this error but in my case they do not work for me.

Comment: Hello @Fernandogs97. Welcome on SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other SO users can help you the best way.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the column names of the table exist in the matrix

[Check this link](https://statisticsglobe.com/check-if-column-exists-in-data-frame-in-r)

If it exists, just set the value as usual.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, the problem here is that this part of the code is prepared for be integrated in a loop that must be run 1000 times.

Comment: You can repeat the process every time.